# I want to add a list to a dictionary I created from a SELECT db.execute query then loop through the updated dictionary

Tags: python, sql, list, dictionary

I have the following code to query a database of stock purchases:

```
dicts = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(balance) FROM portfolio")
```

This outputs:

```
[{'symbol': 'F', 'SUM(balance)': 59.55}, {'symbol': 'MSI', 'SUM(balance)': 1374.1999999999998}]
```

and a list (called "total") that I created to convert the SUM(balance) number to a currency

```
for item in db.execute("SELECT SUM(balance) FROM portfolio GROUP BY symbol"):
        total.append(usd(item["SUM(balance)"]))
```

Which outputs:

```
['$59.55', '$1,374.20']
```

How do I add the items in total[] to dicts so it outputs this:

```
[{'symbol': 'F', 'SUM(balance)': 59.55, 'total': $59.55}, {'symbol': 'MSI', 'SUM(balance)': 1374.1999999999998, 'total': $1,374.20}]
```

I ultimately want to run a for loop over dicts that includes the values in total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re barking up the wrong tree. Just add the `GROUP BY` clause to your first query and eliminate the second query.

You didn’t mention which DBMS you’re using (later; identified as sqlite3), but it shouldn’t be possible to use an aggregate function like `SUM` without a `GROUP BY`.

The easy way to convert a real-number column to a string is to just prepend your `$` to it:

```
select “$” || sum(balance)
```

SQLite will convert (coerce) the value to a string. In other DBMSs, or other circumstances in SQLite, you might need to do an explicit case instead:

```
select “$” || cast(balance as text)
```

One last option for you. Use your original query that returns a number, and handle the format as field-level formatting in the UI. It’s not usual to handle currency as a string. Depending on the specific field or form control you use in Flask, this should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm using an sql database.  If I add the GROUP BY to the first query it will output the wrong format for SUM(balance) number.  For example, it outputs 59.55 but I want it to be $59.55.  I'm using flask to output the data on a website.

Comment: Which specific DBMS are you using — MS SQL Server, MySql or ?? It’s easy to do a format conversion in a select statement. Once I know what DBMS you’re using I can give you specific advice.

Comment: I'm using sqlite3

Comment: Thanks for the help! The easiest solution for me was to add {{ "$%.2f"|format(item["SUM(balance)"]) }} to my html page.  Worked perfect.